# Assign total value of month to each day of month

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d5c1dc74a38165f286f4b9b72d159f9)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    country VARCHAR(255),
    sales_date DATE,
    sales_volume DECIMAL,
    fix_costs DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO sales
(country, sales_date, sales_volume, fix_costs
)
VALUES 

('DE', '2020-01-03', '500', '0'),
('FR', '2020-01-03', '350', '0'),
('None', '2020-01-31', '0', '2000'),

('DE', '2020-02-15', '0', '0'),
('FR', '2020-02-15', '0', '0'),
('None', '2020-02-29', '0', '5000'),

('DE', '2020-03-27', '180', '0'),
('FR', '2020-03-27', '970', '0'),
('None', '2020-03-31', '0', '4000');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
sales_date    |  country    |  sales_volume     |     fix_costs
--------------|-------------|-------------------|-----------------
2020-01-03    |     DE      |         500       |       2000
2020-01-03    |     FR      |         350       |       2000
2020-02-15    |     DE      |           0       |       5000
2020-02-15    |     FR      |           0       |       5000
2020-03-27    |     DE      |         180       |       4000
2020-03-27    |     FR      |         970       |       4000
```

---

As you can see in my table I have a total of `fix_costs` assigned to the **last day of each month**.

In my results I want to assign this total of `fix_costs` to **each day of the month**. 
Therefore, I tried to go with this query:

```
SELECT
s.sales_date, 
s.country,
s.sales_volume,
f.fix_costs
FROM sales s

JOIN

  (SELECT 
  ((date_trunc('MONTH', sales_date) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 DAY')::date) AS month_ld,
  SUM(fix_costs) AS fix_costs
  FROM sales
  WHERE country = 'None'
  GROUP BY month_ld) f ON f.month_ld = LAST_DAY(s.sales_date)

WHERE country <> 'None'
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

For this query I get an error on the `LAST_DAY(s.sales_date)` since this expression does not exist in PostgresSQL. 
However, I have no clue how I can replace it correctly in order to get the expected result.

Can you help me?

---

([MariaDB Fiddle as comparison](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=ceeb06736f251fffe5476bb728482e89))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6362445025a9e2b1384f12b366708b1f)

```
SELECT
    s1.sales_date,
    s1.country,
    s1.sales_volume,
    s2.fix_costs
FROM sales s1
JOIN sales s2 ON s1.country <> 'None' AND s2.country = 'None' 
    AND date_trunc('month', s1.sales_date) = date_trunc('month', s2.sales_date)
```

You need a natural self-join. Join conditions are:

1. First table **without** `None` records (`s1.country <> 'None'`)
2. Second table **only** `None` records (`s2.country = 'None'`)
3. Date: Only consider year and month part, ignore days. This can be achieved by normalizing the dates of both tables to the first of the month by using `date_trunc()`. So, e.g. `'2020-02-15'` results in `'2020-02-01'` and `'2020-02-29'` results in `'2020-02-01'` too, which works well as comparision and join condition.

**Alternatively**:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        sales_date,
        country,
        sales_volume,
        SUM(fix_costs) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', sales_date)) as fix_costs
    FROM sales 
) s
WHERE country <> 'None'
```

You can use the `SUM()` window function over the group of `date_trunc()` as described above. Then you need filter the `None` records afterwards

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation and the date_trunc() formula. Just for my documenation I could also go with this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5af655f7cfc092e1384677a6bf032a6b

Comment: @Michi If you want to do it your way, I recommend to use window functions to make the code a bit simpler. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, use window functions:

```
select s.*,
       sum(fix_costs) over (partition by date_trunc(sales_date)) as month_fixed_costs
from sales;
```

Note that this assumes that fixed costs are `NULL` or `0` on other days -- which is true for the data in the question.